# What does it mean for the Second Fundamental Form to be 'Trivial'?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, submanifold

I have seen this written down and wanted to check on the meaning.  When someone states that the scalar second fundamental form is trivial, does that mean that the second fundamental form vanishes and hence that the submanifold is totally geodesic, or that the second fundamental form takes some trivial form?

Comment: I've never heard this usage of 'trivial' before, but I'd find it confusing for it to indicate anything other than $\operatorname{II} = 0$ (everywhere).

Comment: If $X$ is the submanifold and $\nu$ its normal bundle then $\Pi$ is a section in $\mathrm{Hom}(S^2(TX),\nu)$. The Levi-Civita connection induces a connection on this bundle, so it makes sense to speak of 'parallel second fundamental form'. Maybe that's what was meant with 'trivial'?